# Do purple monsters have a higher chance of dropping magic  and better quality items than white monsters?

Tags: diablo-iii

Since the 1.03 patch, it often feels as the purple monsters (unique monsters, often related to quests (e.g. the monster which spawns when you retrieve Zoltun Kulle's head)) drop really crappy loot. Oftentimes, they only drop a couple of gold piles. Do purple monsters have a better chance of dropping magic, rare and legendary items than white monsters?

To clarify what I am looking for:

**Is the chance to get magic (or rare/legendary) items any greater from unique purple-named minibosses than from normal white monsters?**

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "Good loot"?

Comment: @Wipqozn What I mean is: Do they have a larger chance of dropping magic/rare/legendary items than a normal white monster? If the chances to get good loot is no better than for normal white monsters, then there is no point in fighting them. It is more economically efficient to just run past them and fight a white monster instead, receiving the same loot, but at easier difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a bug with 1.03. The [patch notes for 1.03a](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6514995/Patch_103a_Now_Live-6_26_2012#blog) state that this was fixed:

> Fixed a bug that was causing Unique monsters to not drop the appropriate amount of loot when slain

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you expect the loot to be better simply based on the type of monster (namely, a boss or mini-boss).  This is not the case.  While these monsters are guaranteed to drop X items that are magic (or later, possibly rare) or above, the ratios of magic:rare:legendary:set is still the same.  You simply remove the lower tier items from those calculations. So, if the ratios are 100 magic per 25 rares per 5 legendary per 1 set (and I know those aren't the right ratios, but bear with me), then you still have a 100/131 = 76% chance of getting a magic item, regardless of the monster you just defeated.

While your magic find is effectively 100% on these monsters, the loot that they drop is just as good as any other monster that happens to pass the magic find check.

Comment: The thing is that they are not guaranteed to drop any magic items, like you say. Most of the time they only drop a couple of gold piles. A few times I've experienced them dropping no loot whatsoever (not even a single gold coin, not even a white normal item). I think you must be talking about the blue monsters (the randomly generated champion packs which spawn with affixes like fire chains, molten etc. visible below their names). These monsters are not what I am talking about. I am talking about the unique, purple-named monsters.

Comment: @Alderath: You're still on normal, aren't you?  In that case, X = 0.  You have the exact same chance of higher tier loot with those particular monsters as you do with everyone else.

Comment: I am talking about inferno, but I'd assume the situation is the same for any difficulty. Are you sure that you understand the difference between blue-named and purple-named monsters? Purple-named monsters are not guaranteed to drop anything (as least not in inferno)...

Comment: In my experience, purple named monsters are not guaranteed to drop blue/yellow items.  Blue/Yellow monsters are not technically guaranteed to do so either (unless you have 5 stacks of Nephalim Valor, post patch 1.0.3), but for all practical purposes drop "Better Loot".  Purple monsters simply have a higher chance of dropping more loot than a white monster.  Last night, in Act 1 of inferno, I got 3 yellow items from a purple monster and in the same game, only 1 blue item from another.